# Streaming a stringstream within a stringstream Code compiles for GCC until V5.5 but not the following versions

Tags: c++, gcc, stringstream

I have the following C++ code that compiles successfully for gcc < v5.5

```
#include <sstream>

namespace util
{

   inline void operator << (std::stringstream& stream, const char* data)
   {
      data = data ? data : "(null)";
      std::operator<<(stream, data);
   }
}

class Record
{
public:

   template<typename T>
   Record& operator<<(const T& data)
   {
      using namespace util;
      m_message << data;
    //   std::cout << data << std::endl;
      return *this;
   }
   
private:
   std::stringstream m_message;
};

int main()
{   
    Record r;
    std::stringstream m;
    r << m; //Error after gcc5.5
    r << m.str(); //Ok in both
    return 0;
    
}
```

Looks like passing a stringstream to a stringstream is no longer valid. I'm not sure why.

Here's a link for comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/novWE3so8

Comment: [Use correct header files 1st please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: AFAIK, that has never been part of any standard. It's possible that old g++ versions implemented it (the standard is only a minimum) and it was removed.

Comment: Issue with whatever extensions is that those can be removed after whoever sponsored these decided to stop. What overload of << you expect that code to call? Tell the number from list: <https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt>

Comment: @ÖöTiib That's not complete, though, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

Comment: @ÖöTiib, well, it doens't match any parameters there. Maybe this is no longer implemented by compilers as molbdhilo stated.

Comment: @BilalAhmed so you should add your own overload ... like Record& operator<<(const std::stringstream& m) ... if all you want is just to output m.str(), it will compile on other compilers and more modern gcc and that is usually benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not depend on the gcc version, but rather on the C++-Standard Version you're compiling for.

Your example works without problems with the latest gcc version when compiling for C++03: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1q5WMMW3b)

---

The reason why this compiles at all is that pre-C++11 there was no `bool` datatype.
Checking if a stream is valid (e.g. `if(stream) { /*...*/ }`) therefore was mandated to just return some unspecified boolean-like type:

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

> ```
> operator /* unspecified-boolean-type */() const; // (until C++11)
> explicit operator bool() const; // (since C++11)
> ```

Note that the conversion also was implicit pre C++11, since [explicit conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) were added in C++11.

libstdc++ happens to define the conversion operator as follows: [github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.h#L120-L126)

```cpp
///@{
/**
 *  @brief  The quick-and-easy status check.
 *
 *  This allows you to write constructs such as
 *  <code>if (!a_stream) ...</code> and <code>while (a_stream) ...</code>
 */
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      explicit operator bool() const { return !this->fail(); }
#else
      operator void*() const { return this->fail() ? 0 : const_cast<basic_ios*>(this); }
#endif
```

Note that this allows an *implicit* (!) conversion from any stream to `void*`.

Which is unfortunate, given that `std::basic_ostream` provides an overload for outputting pointers:
[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

```cpp
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value ); // (8)
```

---

So what actually happens in your example is that the stream is implicitly converted to a `void*` pointer, and then `operator<<(const void*)` is called to output that pointer.

Which is probably not what you wanted to happen:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xGsfqW3jP)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream m;
    m << "foobar";

    std::stringstream ss;
    // equivalent to  ss << static_cast<void*>(&m);
    ss << m;

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    // will print the address of m, e.g. 0x7ffcda4c2540
    // NOT foobar!
    return 0;
}
```

---

##### The correct way to append a stream

C++ `std::istream`s can be written to `std::ostreams` by just passing the underlying stream buffer instead of the whole stream, e.g.:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bvG8nno64)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream m;
    m << "foobar";

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << m.rdbuf(); // append everything from m to ss

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So your example could be fixed like this:

```cpp
// r << m;
r << m.rdbuf();
```